# How to set position of list of figure (lof) in R bookdown YAML

Tags: r, yaml, bookdown

I have a R bookdown whose YAML looks like this:

```
    ---
title: "My title"
toc: False
lof: True
author: "the author"
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2: 
    keep_tex: yes
    ---
```

By default it generates a pdf file with the list of figures at the beginning just after the title.
Is there a way to have this list at the end, after the references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `lof: True` and add `\listoffigures` after your references.